# Can't deploy from Remix - network does not support EIP-1559

Tags: remix, metamask, eip-1559

I am trying to deploy a smart contract from Remix using the following settings:

compiler: 0.8.0
EVM version: compiler default
Environment: injected Web3 (metamask connected to hardwarewallet, main (1) network)
Gas limit: 8000000
value: 0

When I click deploy I get the following error:

> Invalid transaction params: params specify an EIP-1559 transaction but
> the current network does not support EIP-1559

I can neither find any information on what causes this error nor how to solve it - any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit:
This seems to be the reason (from the metamask webpage):

> How does EIP-1559 work with Trezor/Ledger integration on MetaMask?
> Trezor and Ledger do not yet support EIP-1559 so MetaMask will fall
> back to pre EIP-1559 gas controls.

https://metamask.io/1559.html

If I change my account in Metamask to a wallet without ledger/trezor I don't get the error.

Comment: Thats super wierd, you're saying that you're deploying on mainnet (which definitely supports EIP-1559), and yet remix seems to be telling you the opposite. Care to share your code?

Comment: Indeed very weird. The error shows in remix before the transaction even gets to metamask. Maybe metamask is not updated yet?

Comment: they state on the metamask webpage that ledger doesn't support EIP-1559 maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Oh, thats definitely it yes. Not much you can do then

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your EVM version to London.

Comment: I don't have London as an option in Remix on Firefox

Comment: you get to select the EVM version during compilation on the Solidity Compiler section of Remix

Comment: Still works in 2023 :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to deploy on Polygon.  If you switch Metamask to another chain, e.g. if you're on Polygon, switch to Ethereum and then switch back, then Metamask gets triggered and it works.